# Need help in modelling a delay element in Simulink

Tags: matlab, delay, simulink

I need to generate a pulse which steps from 0 to 1 after an initial predetermined time has elapsed. When the new predetermined time is available, the pulse should again step from 1 to 0. It should step from 0 to 1 after that time has elapsed. This model has to be implemented in Simulink.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the times at which the on/off behaviours are to be performed are available before the model simulation begins. Let's say that it's 2 seconds of value 0 and then 3 seconds of value 1.

Use the `Pulse Generator` block in the `Sources` library of Simulink. The trick is starting with a zero. To do this, set the `Amplitude` to 1 second, the `Period` to 5s, the `Pulse Width` to 60% and the `Phase Delay` to 2s.

The output will look as below.

[image: PulseGenerator]